# Typeorm update record in OneToMany relation

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have the following two entities with a OneToMany/ManyToOne relation between them:

```
@Entity({ name: 'user' })
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar' })
  firstName: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar' })
  lastName: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Group, group => group.id)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'groupId' })
  group: Group;

  @Column({ type: 'integer' })
  groupId: number;
}
```

```
@Entity({ name: 'group' })
export class Group {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('increment')
  id: number;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar' })
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(() => User, user => user.group)
  members: User[];
}
```

When I create a new group in my Group repository, I can add existing members as follows:

```
const group = new Group();
group.name = 'Test';
group.members = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }]; // user ids
this.save(group);
```

I am wondering if I can update existing members in a similar way. For example if a group with id 1 has two members:

```
{ id: 1, firstName: 'Member', lastName: 'One', groupId: 1 }
{ id: 2, firstName: 'Member', lastName: 'Two', groupId: 1 }
```

Is it possible to update a member through the OneToMany relation in a similar way as I'm adding them ? Something like (making this up):

```
const group = await repository.findOne(groupId, { relations: ['members'] });
group.members = [{ id: 1, firstName: 'Updated' }]; // this would update the firstName of member with id 1 if it exists in the relation
repository.save(group);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried {cascade:true} option in relationships?

Answer (score 4):

There is no built in functionality in typeorm to update specific related entity from the base entity. However if you want to do this then you can add a general function which updates the base table as well as it's relations.

Comment: Still no built in functionality? I think it is quite important functionality to have?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by {cascade:true} in the enitty